# What is the right way to remove head of a number?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I often have a number for which I want to remove its head, e.g. {1}. I know of two ways to remove the head:

```
{1}[[1]]
# & @@ {1}
```

Neither of these methods seem particularly transparent to me. What is the "right" way to do this common transformation?

Comment: I would do `## & @@ # &`, so the same what you've done but more general, your way fails for {1, 2}.

Comment: Or with pattern matching: `expr /. _[x__] :> x`

Comment: `Identity @@ {1}` or `Sequence @@ {1}` depending on what you want to achieve... but the others seems transparent enough, too.